# Attempting to set registry key

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I am attempting to set a basic registry key name/value pair. I run both regedit as Administrator and I run the program as an Administrator, but the key does not reflect in the regedit view. What is strange is that I successfully hit all the appropriate conditionals...

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif // UNICODE

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;


INT WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    HKEY key;

    if(RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), &key) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout<<"Unable to open reigstry key"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Registry key opened..."<<endl;
        cout<<key;
    }

    if(RegSetValueEx(key, TEXT("value_name"),0,REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)"value_data",strlen("value_data")*sizeof(char)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout<<"unable to set key"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Set the key"<<endl;
        RegCloseKey(key);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your program 32 or 64 bit.  Under 64 bit windows there is a separate set of registry keys for 32 bit programs.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I am running a 64 bit version of Windows, but I do not know what my program is...? I am compiling in code::blocks with gcc

Comment: The current version of code::blocks (16.01) in "project build options" has switches for 32 or 64 bit build.

Comment: If a 32bit app wants to access a 64bit Registry key, it need to use the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag when opening the key. Likewise, use `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` in a 64bit process to access a 32bit key. See [Registry Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx) and [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129.aspx) for more details

Comment: Also, your code is leaking the `HKEY` handle if `RegSetValueEx()` fails. And you are passing `char*` data to `RegSetValueEx()`, so you should use `RegSetValueExA()` directly instead of the `TCHAR` version of `RegSetValueEx()`.